# How to extract a jar to a particular location?

Tags: java, shell, jar

I am using

```
jar -xf <name of the jar> -C <location where jar is to be extracted>
```

But i am getting issues with the syntax.

Please let me know where i am wrong or site some example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
unzip -d /path/to/your/directory  my.jar
```

as if the `jar` file as a `zip` file.

Answer (score 1):

JARs are packed with ZIP. `unzip -d [target-directory] [jar-file]` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

just work with it like the common archive (7z, zip)